# Old KVM Guest not starting after reboot

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-18.04, libvirt, qemu

I have a bunch of Virtual Machines in a Ubuntu 18 Guest machine. Until recently they have all been working without any problem. However after I restartet one of the Guests(also Ubuntu) it is now not starting back up.
The libvirt log does have nothing out of the ordinary, If I mount the guest image the last log entry is from the shutdown.
After starting the guest there is 0 CPU usage for this machine and very little and constant memory usage. `virsh shutdown Guest` has no effect.
There where no changes or updates before this happend.

The images are in a zfs pool and have hourly snapshots, however those are also not booting anymore.

I really don't know how to debug this anymore, there is not a single error message.

I am thankful for any help.

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using library: libvirt 4.0.0
Using API: QEMU 4.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.11.1
```

Comment: Look at the VM console.

Comment: I did and did not get a single line in response

Comment: What? Is the screen blank? What do you see when you reset the VM? Take screenshots using the Take screenshot menu item.

Comment: So you see the qemu process running, but the console is blank? Try starting from an installer image or live image to check.